# how to get image (file) by $_POST in mvc

Tags: php, file, post, model-view-controller

i would like to ask, how to get file(image) from my form.php ,then move file in another folder and get path of picture in Controller.php.
I am not sure how to get that file from post.

form.php

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="image" type="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Uložit článok" />
</form>
```

Controller.php

```
 $folder_path  "images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]
 $folder = "images/";
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "$folder" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
 $Manager->AddPhoto($folder); //this is just adding into database
```

Comment: What MVC framework are you using? It matters.

Comment: i am just learning php and mvc and how it works, i am not using framework, i just mean how to get that file(image) from this html form in php file

Comment: Oh, then the answer below is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag. which MVC framework you are using? check the [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's almost done. The best is decide the final destination by your own.

Let's suppose you have a folder called myPhotos. And the destination file is the datetime or timestamp that you can obtain with microtime(), also you can get the extension of the file with pathinfo. After all the destination files will be:

myphotos/123456myfile.jpg

Having this path, you can use this for move_uploaded_file and later for store in database.